# Eclipse JPA Tools - Hibernate reverse engineering rules

Tags: eclipse, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to get all JPA entities to generate with a consistent Java type when generating the types from an Oracle database. In particular, all NUMBER types should generate as BigDecimal. In some cases, they generate as a long (primitive) when they are not nullable, other times they generate as a BigDecimal. The problem lies that when relationships are created, the ones that generate as BigDecimal sometimes have a relationship to those as long, which is incompatible. Long is incorrect by default anyway, as they can have decimal values in them.

I feel it's primarily a problem with the fact the Oracle NUMBER type can be either numeric or decimal, but still need to figure out how to get the tooling to handle it.

I'm using the standard Eclipse (STS) JPA tooling, with Hibernate configured as the JPA provider. Hibernate tools are not installed, nor is it presently an option. On the last screen of "Generate entities from tables", it gives you the option to customize individual entities, but foreign keys do not show up (the ones I'd have to change to make them compatible).

Any ideas on how to control this mapping through the standard JPA tools with a configured Hibernate provider in Eclipse/STS?